# No route matches [GET] "/update_states"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating simple dynamic selection using [this](http://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/) guide.

I am halfway done finaly, but when I select region from dropdown, it doesn't show any sub records. In my case States.

I examinated error using Firebug I got [theese](http://gyazo.com/93c97d01fbcae6a7f693c935be0b62e3) errors right after I select region. It says

```
No route matches [GET] "/update_states"
```

But I double checked my routes.rb file and there is like this:

```
get 'home/update_states', as: 'update_states'
get 'home/show'
```

So I am wondering what could couse this error ?

**Home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @form = Form.new
    @regions = Region.all
    @states = State.where("region_id = ?", @regions.first.id)
  end

  def show
    @state = State.where("id = ?", params[:form][:state_id])
  end

  def update_states
    @states = State.where("region_id = ?", params[:region_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the routes to include controller and action.

```
get 'home/update_states' => 'home#update_states', as: 'update_states'
get 'home/show' => 'home#show'
```

This mapping requires that you have a `HomeController` with two methods (actions) `update_states` and `show`.

The second problem is that you are doing a `Get` on `/update_states`, but you haven't mapped it!

Try hitting `/home/update_states` route instead.

To check all available routes and mappings, use `rake routes` in your console.

Edit:

Ok, so looking at your `HomeController`, your `update_states` action looks for states with `region_id` matching `params[:region_id]`. But this isn't being passed anywhere!

One way to do this would be to change the route to be something like:

```
get 'home/:region_id/update_states' => 'home#update_states', as: 'update_states'
```

This will then change the routes to be

```
GET /home/12/update_states
```

This will look for states with `region_id=12`.

Note that this is just one way of passing parameter, and you need to ensure that the route pattern isn't clashing.

Comment: You need to tell us what the controller looks like in your code.

Comment: Acctually it is passed, but not like region_id but like state_id, thats why it's not working `GET http://localhost:3000/home/update_states?state_id=4&_=1410881959885` in firebug.

Comment: I think I am missing something, since you are using `params[:region_id]` in the action. Anyways, good you sorted it out. Please consider marking one of the responses as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Acctualy I fixed itwith your help. I had mixed up in home.js.coffee file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above does not reference properly to controller#action. Make it like so,

```
get 'home/update_states' => 'home#update_states', as: 'update_states'
get 'home/show' => 'home#show'
```

Comment: Thanks, but still shows the same error `No route matches [GET] "/update_states"`

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the best way is :

```
 match '/update_states' => 'home#update_states', :as => 'update_states'
 match '/show', to: 'home#show', via: 'get'
```

Comment: Thanks, but still error :`No route matches {:action=>"show", :locale=>:lv, :controller=>"home"}`

Comment: yep, because you have no show.html.erb file into Views.

Comment: crap 'resources :homes do'

Comment: 'match '/update_states' => 'home#update_states', :as => 'update_states''
' match '/show',  to: 'home#show', via: 'get''

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest that learning resourceful routes is worth the time.  If you want your routes to be top level (without /home in front) you can do something like this.

```
  scope '/', controller: :home do
    get :update_states
    get :show
  end
```

This DRYer as it automatically makes url helpers (no as: necessary) and it is clear which controller and action you are using.